# Opening a file on Google Drive directly in a Google Drive App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps

If I open the shareable link I have got for a file from Google Drive in the browser, I always get either to the Drive's internal preview program or to a download page (See below).

I would like to know whether there is a programmatic way to launch a specific drive-connected application (with confirmed access permissions) to open a file for which I have the link (and thus, the ID as well).

I don't want to do this through the drive's interface, but rather within my program. Let's say I want to let the users browse their files and open them in the browser with their default app as they have defined it on their drive (and let's say I already know that app).

To make it clear, I just want to achieve what Google Drive's interface does in the browser: You click a file, and it opens in a new tab in your default app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is possible with the use of [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive#top_of_page) and [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/#top_of_page).

**Advanced Drive Service**

> The advanced Drive service allows you to use the Google Drive web API in Apps Script. Much like Apps Script's built-in Drive service, this API allows scripts to create, find, and modify files and folders in Google Drive. In most cases, the built-in service is easier to use, but this advanced service provides a few extra features, including access to custom file properties as well as revisions for files and folders.

and for the **Drive Service**, you can use `getUrl()` method to get the URL that can be used to open the File in a Google App like Drive or Docs.

> This service  allows scripts to create, find, and modify files and folders in Google Drive.

Detailed information and sample codes regarding these services can be found in the documentations.

Comment: The question is not about opening a file in my app. Of course that is possible. The question is about opening a file in "an app".